# Getting error as EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: and uncaught

Tags: angular

```
productsearch.service.ts


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { URLSearchParams, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class ProductsearchService {

  private _url: string = 'app/apidata/products.json'

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {}

  search(term: string) {
    console.log(this.term);
    var search = new URLSearchParams()

    search.set('action', 'opensearch');

    search.set('search', term);

    search.set('format', 'json');

    return this.jsonp

                .get('app/apidata/products.json?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK', { search})
                .map((request) => request.json()[1]);
  }
```

**productsearch.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable}       from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ProductsearchService } from './productsearch.service';


@Component({
    selector:'app-productsearch',
    template:`<h1>product search</h1>
    <input type="text" [formControl]="term">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let p of products | async">{{p.ITEM}}</li>
      </ul>

    `

})

export class ProductsearchComponent{

 products: Observable<Array<string>>;
  term = new FormControl();
  constructor(private productsearchService: ProductsearchService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.term.valueChanges
                 .debounceTime(400)
                 .distinctUntilChanged()
                 .switchMap(term => this.productsearchService.search(term));
  }

}
}
```

I created input button to search data in products.json file
    but I got error as:

> EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: app/apidata/products.json?callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished&action=opensearch&search=asa &format=json

and

> Subscriber.ts:241 Uncaught Response {_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers…

Comment: products.json should be valid jsonp format. Is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this Issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8153

You try to read a Json file with JsonP. Wrap it like in this example : http://jsonpwrapper.com/